# Clear button not clearing textbox field php

Tags: php, sql-update, cleartext

I'm creating a simple site since I'm still studying. We have an activity which includes user signup, viewing of records of the signed up users, editing/updating records. In updating, once the user click edit, an update form wil show with its textboxes filled with the values of the row that the user wanted to edit. My problem is when the user click clear button, it's not working, i need to use php for clearing.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ortegadb");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Attempt select query execution
$id = $_REQUEST["userid"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usertb WHERE id=$id";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $username = $row["username"];
            $password= $row["password"];
            $fullname = $row["fullname"];
           
    
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Update</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        form {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            max-width: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    // Your PHP code here...
    ?>

<form action="updaterecord.php" method="POST">

<h2><center>Update</center></h2> <br>
Userid:
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?> "><br>
Username
<input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $username ?> "><br>
Full Name:
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname ?> "><br>
Password:
<input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo $password ?> "><br>
<input type="submit" name="sbt" value="Update">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using javascript but we're not allowed to use it and besides it is still not working. I also tried just making the values "" but not working still.

Comment: the `<input type="reset">` element will set all fields in form to their original state, it will not set them to empty when they weren't at the beginning. you might misunderstood what you were asked to do. in case you really want to set all fields to be empty change `type="reset"` to submit, give it name and then check for its presence in post data, this way you can detect which button was used to submit the form and act accordingly. your code is vulnerable to the sql injection, as you do not sanitize user input from `$_REQUEST["userid"]`, use prepared statements there to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript

First change the reset button with a simple button:

```html
<input id="clear-button" type="button" value="Clear" >
```

and then add a listener on click:

```html
<script>

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

        document.getElementById("clear-button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

            e.target.form.querySelectorAll("input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit])").forEach( (el) => {
                el.value = '';
            })
        });

    });

</script>
```